How to navigate to a blazor page from Maui Xaml page
I know how to navigate from Blazor to Maui using
App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());

but how do I go the other way around? I have a razor component in my maui app and another in my shared class library and
`Navigationmanager.NavigateTo("/myBlazorPage")

isnt working from my Maui XAML.cs page. When the breakpoint hits nothing happens. No screens change, nothing
I can't seem to figure this out and need assistance

I don't think we could navigate from a Maui page to razor component as their route ways are much different. For a walkaround, you could wrap razor component in a Maui ContentPage.
An usage example:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiBlazor"
             >

    <BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Main}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>

</ContentPage>

And then use maui navigation:
 App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MauiPages.MyPage());

